# flycheck tslint reports no-implicit-dependencies for everything

Tags: flycheck, javascript

I'm editing TypeScript using [Tide](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide), successfully, except that it complains about every single `import` statement.  For example:

```
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
```

I see an error in the minibuffer:

> Module 'graphql' is not listed as dependency in package.json [no-implicit-dependencies]

My repository layout is like so:

```
<repository root>
\-- service
  +-- package.json
  +-- tslint.yml
  \-- src
    \-- something.ts
```

If I go and open up the `package.json` file it's right there, and if I run `tslint` outside Emacs or in a `*shell*` buffer it works fine.  All of the other type checking works fine and I happily get JavaScript type errors, it's just this one complaint, almost as if it's not finding `package.json` where it expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to have been [a known issue in flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1420) and updating to the `melpa` version of flycheck fixes it.  (My `.emacs` file prefers `melpa-stable` packages, even though they can be mildly dated.  I think I need a version from at least 20180309, but “stable” version 31 is from 7 Oct 2017.)